# Orientation on PHP framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony

I'm thinking in learning Zend or Symfony frameworks but I don`t know which one to choose or if I really need them at all.

I usually develop small to medium web apps (management apps), I have my own classes to quickly develop database connections and data grids, maybe could improve in form development as I still build them quite "hand made". So far, I don't find a problem to program "spaghetti code" in small projects, maybe in medium ones it's time to think in MVC.

So, I wonder where to invest my efforts:

1. Improve my own classes that fit my (limited) needs
2. Learn Symfony 2
3. Learn Zend

My main concern is if I really need a framework or not and I know that there are many questions and opinions about *symfony vs zend*, I read them and the conclusion is: *"it's up to you, they are both good"*, I know that, but I'd like to hear your opinions having this in count:

My goal is to find a way to develop faster, as for MVC standard I know they are similar. Also, which one is better if you want to develop for desktop and mobile devices? are there any built in utilities for this? How about forms? Which ones are more programmer friendly?

I also develop in ASP.NET and one thing I don't like of .NET is the difficult integration of client and server, I mean, if you choose to program with server controls, JavaScript does not integrate well and you better manage events in server, so a better client/server integration is also welcome.

Your opinions are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are going to create small / medium apps you don't need Zend or Symfony, they're both too large and to heavy frameworks, I'm using Kohana and I'm very happy with choice.

Kohana is simple to start, code is very simple to look at and analyze.

In Zend and Symfony classes are combining with each other so if you are looking for some anwsers you have to look in 2, 3 or even more files.

Think about some other frameworks at beginning after a while you can change them to bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, developing an MVC framework yourself can be a very valuable experience. You would learn about coding techniques during the process which you may not learn if you are just building on top of an existing framework.

I recently started reading more about MVC frameworks and various tutorials about ways in which people structure their own framework and decided to start building my own.

There are tutorials on Youtube which you could use for the base of your new framework, or build off something simple like CodeIgniter.

On the other hand, if you would like to work with either of the frameworks you mentioned in the future, your experience working with those could be used on your CV/resume.

Answer (score 0):

Its not only learning the MVC frameworks such as Zend that will help, but the inevitable learning of OOP principles that will become immensely valuable to you. I say go for it, when you start using them you will realise there potential to create scaleable web apps.

Also, think of a project, choose a framework and set yourself up on github and go to work. I think thats the best way to find out, by doing.

Also, as a sidenote: check out codeigniter. Its great.